# Can a $3\times3$ matrix have more than $3$ linear independent eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand you can do multiples of eigenvectors, but suppose they are a linear independent. Can there be more than $n$ for a $n\times n$ matrix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forget being eigenvectors -- you can't have more than three linearly-independent vectors in a three-dimensional space.  In fact, that's literally the definition of "three-dimensional."

Comment: Actually the definition of $n$-dimensional is having a basis containing $n$ vectors. That this excludes having another set of $n+1$ independent vectors is a fundamental theorem (which is surprisingly hard to prove formally).

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is no.

Consider a 3D space, it will require only 3 linearly independent vectors to span it. Anything else will automatically be a combination of the three vectors. (x,y,z)

Or a 2D plane, only two independent vectors(lines) can span the entire plane. Any other line can be expressed as a combination of the other two independent lines.